# Connot read file from resource folder when I run the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, io

my program work fine wen i start the server via eclipse, when I start the server via java - jar myjar.jar

i got this error :

file java.io.FileNotFoundException:

`file:\D:\projets\dev\filegenerator\target\myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\reports.csv (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de rÚpertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)`

wheni tried to read the file from resources folders via classLoader.

how can I solve this problem when I start the jar ?

Thank you

Comment: Ah, the good old "I can't read my file in the jar" issue.  Basically, a Jar is just a zip file, so if you try and read a file contained within it like a normal file, it file, because it's not a normal file any more - it's just a packet series of bytes along with a bunch of other packet bytes.  Instead, you should make use of `Class#getResource` (or `Class#getResourceAsStream` as you needs require)

Comment: I do this : `new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)`  what should I do to work in the jar ?

Comment: You CAN NOT use `File`, it just won't work, it doesn't make sense.  What you trying to access IS NOT A FILE, it's a binary stream contained within a larger binary file.  Personally, unless you dealing with some weird class loading environment, `getClass().getResource(fileName)` should be enough to get you a `URL` reference to the resource